# How to make a button in android and make it invisible

Tags: android-widget

I want to have a button which should not be visible but when clicked onclick should be executed..

I have tried making

Button button;
1)button.setVisiblity(4);//it made it invisible but onclick was not working

2)In the layout xml i have attached android:visibilty="invisible" //but it made it invisible

Answer (score 0):

Remove the visibility bit and use the following instead.

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```